# How to print a histogram from the values in an array in reverse order with nested for loops

Tags: java

I have assignment where I have to print and fill an array consisting of 50 indices with random integers then print the values out. Then below that print a list of the numbers in the reverse index with a histogram next to each value. Im supposed to use a nested for loop to solve this and only could get the first section of the problem so far. This is my first time using stackoverflow and I am not expecting an upright answer but if someone could help me understand nested for loops a little more, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      Random ranGen = new Random();
      
      int[] ranArray = new int [SIZE];
      
      char stars = '*';
      
      System.out.println("Array: " + "\n");
      
      for(int i = 0; i < ranArray.length; i++) {
         
         int rangeLimit = ranGen.nextInt((45 - 5) + 1) + 5;
         
         ranArray[i] = ranGen.nextInt(rangeLimit);
         
         System.out.println(ranArray[i]);
         
            for(int j = 0; j < ranArray[i]; j++) {
         
               System.out.println("Histrogram");

               System.out.println(ranArray[i] );
         
         }
              
      }
      
   }

}
```

[How the output of the code should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eldDF.png)

Comment: What should be the output of this program. could you add it to the question ?

Comment: @OsamaAbdulRehman Thank you for the quick reply! I just made an edit with an attached picture of how it should output. Thank you.

Comment: @OsamaAbdulRehman So I got everything working now thanks to you, but one of the requirements was to fill the array with numbers in the range 5-45 inclusive. Which I thought I did in this section. ```int rangeLimit = ranGen.nextInt((45 - 5) + 1) + 5;
         
         ranArray[i] = ranGen.nextInt(rangeLimit); ``` But when it out puts theres numbers in the array outside the range. Any info on where I messed up?

Comment: The line ```ranArray[i] = ranGen.nextInt(rangeLimit);``` is not needed, as ```int rangeLimit = ranGen.nextInt((45 - 5) + 1) + 5;``` itself generates the random number between 5 and 45.

Answer (score 2):

For the second section, you can iterate on each random number again and for each number, print it with `System.out.printf("%-5d", number)` ("%-5d" pads the number with spaces to the right) and have a nested loop from `0` to `number-1` and print the start with `System.out.print(stars)`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int SIZE = 5;

        Random ranGen = new Random();

        int[] ranArray = new int[SIZE];

        char stars = '*';

        System.out.println("Array: " + "\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < ranArray.length; i++) {

            int rangeLimit = ranGen.nextInt((45 - 5) + 1) + 5;

            ranArray[i] = ranGen.nextInt(rangeLimit);

            System.out.println(ranArray[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        System.out.println("Histograms:");

        for (int i = ranArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.printf("%-5d", ranArray[i]);

            for (int j=0; j<ranArray[i]; j++) {
                System.out.print(stars);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AlexRudenko you're right, just edited it.